# When Using Postgresql JDBC, INSERT statement that will result in 0 rows being inserted

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, insert

When Using Postgresql JDBC, Insert row with executeUpdate statement but result was zero. I found that data was inserted. API document tells that executeUpdate method return affected row count.

```
mSqlInsertEventHist = "INSERT INTO " + DatabaseTables.EVENT_HIST +
" ( event_id, mntr_id, mntr_zone, mntr_name, mntr_class_name, mntr_class_sub_type, host_name, ip_addr, " +
"   metric_id, metric_name, perf_name, object_name, event_type, event_master_id, " +
"   event_name, event_level, event_msg, threshold, event_recv_day, event_reco_dt, event_recv_dt," +
"   event_saved_dt, blackout_yn, msg_filter_yn ) " +
" VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " + " now() " + ", ?, ? ) ";

mPstmtInstEvtHist.setLong(1, eventid);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setInt(2, mntrid);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(3, mntrZone);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(4, mntrname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(5, mntrClsName);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(6, mntrClsSubType);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(7, hostname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(8, ipAddr);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setInt(9,     Integer.parseInt((String)dataobj.get(MQConstants.METRIC_ID)));
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(10, metricname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(11, perfname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(12, objectname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(13, dataType);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setInt(14, 
Integer.parseInt((String)dataobj.get(MQConstants.EVENT_MASTER_ID)));
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(15, eventname);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(16, eventlvl);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(17, evtMsg);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setObject(18, jsonObj);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setInt(19, 
Integer.parseInt((String)dataobj.get(MQConstants.EVENT_RECV_DAY)));
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setTimestamp(20, colTs);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setTimestamp(21, rcvTs);
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(22, 
(String)dataobj.get(MQConstants.BLACKOUT_YN));
mPstmtInstEvtHist.setString(23, 
(String)dataobj.get(MQConstants.MSG_FILTER_YN));
rtn = mPstmtInstEvtHist.executeUpdate();
if ( rtn == 1  ) {//NOPMD
    Debug.getLogger().trace("Inserted Event into {} => {}, {}, {} " 
   ,DatabaseTables.EVENT_HIST , mntrid, eventname, eventlvl);
} else {
    Debug.getLogger().warn("Failed to insert Event into {} => {}", 
    DatabaseTables.EVENT_HIST, Debug.getString(jobj));
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please show us some code, and data which explain what is happening.

Comment: Row is inserted but always logging Debug.getLogger().warn("Failed to insert Event into {} => {}", 
    DatabaseTables.EVENT_HIST, Debug.getString(jobj));

Comment: Where is the actual `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Added actual INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have a trigger-based partitioning in your database, as described here [in PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.htm).

It's happening completely on the DB side, except that it always returns "0 rows inserted".

Check your DB schema for partitioning triggers in DatabaseTables.EVENT_HIST table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, There were partitioning triggers in EVENT_HIST table